# React Native Bottom Tab Navigation

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native project and i use react-navigations bottom tab navigation in one of the screens.

My question is can i dynamically change one of the icons in it based on which screen am i located ?
For an example i want the middle icon to be dynamic and different for all of the other tabs and when user press some tab i want that icon to change and to have unique functionality.

Do i need to set a callback and pass in every screen that has access and after that callback to re-render the navigator ? - If so will i lose all of the cached & mounted stuff because of the re-render ?

Looking for an optimal solution. Any answer is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to customize the tab a bit, to do so you need to use the custom 
`defaultNavigationOptions` in `createBottomTabNavigator`. defaultNavigationOptions takes in a function of a React component where you get a prop such as `focused, tintColor`, you can do some manipulation using this. If the tab is focused you will get a true value based on that you can change your icon.
For example:

```
const customTabs = ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    if (routeName === 'PageOne') {
      return <View>{focused ? <Icon name='focused' /> : <Icon name='unfocused' /> }</View>
    } else if (routeName === 'PageTwo') {
      return <Text>{routeName} One</Text>
    } else if (routeName === 'PageThree') {
      return <Text>{routeName} One</Text>
    }
  }
});
```

I have added a small example, couldn't figure out how to add a icon to it, so just changing the text, you can replace them with Icon, this will work.
https://snack.expo.io/@subkundu/icon-focused

Let me know if this works. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. But if i am correct your code makes changes on the focused tab icon ?

I want for example if i have 3 tab icons:
When i press Icon 1, the Icon 2 to change along with its functionality for onPress.
When i press Icon 3, the Icon 2 to change along with its functionality for onPress.

Correct me if i understood wrong mate.

Comment: Aha, if thats what you want, I updated the expo, https://snack.expo.io/@subkundu/icon-focused. :)